# Automated installation of FreeBSD

Tags: installation, freebsd

I would like to automate the installation of FreeBSD 8.2 for a project I'm working on. I know the answer to every question in the standard installation, so even a script that just pushes keystrokes would be acceptable. All clues appreciated.

FWIW, I tried this question on the FreeBSD fora (http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=23906) but only got one response that didn't solve the problem. Maybe ServerFaulters will have more ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want install.cfg!  The way the installer works is it first looks for a cfg file on the install media, if it has one it uses that instead of pestering you with silly questions.  You can see the entire automated install procedure (from baremetal) documented here:

http://www.locolomo.org/howto/pxeboot/article.html#SCRIPTING-SYSINSTALL

Comment: That looks great. However, it means that I have to re-make the distro ISO to include the install.cfg. The short bit in section 6.4 looks even more intriguing!

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: The wayback machine has an archived copy [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20111211082642/http://www.locolomo.org/howto/pxeboot/article.html).